# How to set Focus to a TextBox from codebehind when there is postback involved?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a data entry webform there are a few textboxes which cause postback on textchanged event .. I am setting focus to desired textbox after that from codebehind by using ...
`TextBox2.Focus()` BUT this works only on visual studio 2010 and not on 2005. It does not give any error or anything but the focus enters textBox2 for a fraction of second and then vanishes ( probably due to postback).
Note: i have to set focus from code behind only! I am ready to use JavaScript if needed but it has to be run from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following VB.NET code to add javascript to the loaded page after `Postback` :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Set TB Focus", "document.getElementById('" & TextBox2.ClientID & "').focus();", True)
```

This will write the script to the page on postback and this will then execute (as it is not in a function) and set the focus of your textbox.

Also C# Code :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Set Tb Focus", "document.getElementById('" & TextBox2.ClientID & "').focus();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(this), "Focus",
String.Format("document.GetElementById('{0}').focus;", txt.ClientID), true);
```

It registers a javascript and focuses it.

Answer (score 0):

```
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "focus", "document.getElementById('" + txtYourControlName.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```